O365 MS Access Trust Center
I have somewhat confusing issue where I haven't had any luck with solving it.
We are switching from RDS 2k16 to RDS Data Center 2022, and from Office 2016 to Office 365.
I have defined all the GPOs and some of them are not working as they should.
The most recent issue is - i have defined Access Trusted Locations in GPO and if opened from the defined path it opens sucessfully for example: \example.local\AccessFiles\File.mdb
But if user starts MS Access first and tries to open if from the Recent Files, it won't let him, with notification that it is not trusted...but the path is defined all the same.
That being said, even when I open it from the defined path, and it opens without any problems, when I check the Trust Center settings, the box "Allow Trusted Locations on the network" is still not checked even if the GPO is defined and applied.
Do I really have to do it for each user manually, or is there known soulution to this anomaly?
If someone has had a similar problem and solved it, I would be very grateful for your help.

Does the subscription support GPOs?

I think so, it is a ProPlus version, and according to Microsoft its supported

"We are switching from [...] from Office 2016 to Office 365. There is no M365 ProPlus plan.

Indeed, my mistake, the ProPlusRetail is Product ID, the subscription plan is Microsoft 365 Business Premium which should support GPOs

As statet in the documentation: "imited to policies for web apps and privacy policies".

Thank you for the clarification, I have tested it again today, and by some miracle it works...well, kind of... at least now it lets user open recent files from MS Access. (btw. i didn't change anythinG)
"Allow Trusted Locations on the network" is still not applied, and it seems we will have to do it for each user individually, but that's not a big issue.
